# Reduce distance between pictures in landscape mode

Tags: landscape

I Need to reduce the distance between two Pictures in landscape mode. I think they should fit on the page, if the unnecessary spacing wouldnt be there. \hspace{.25cm} doesnt work either. Please find below the Code. And attached the two Pictures, if that helps...[image] [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB01}{fi}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB02}{fl}
%\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{float, afterpage, rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, epstopdf,pgfplots}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb, moreverb, relsize}
\usepackage{eurosym, calc, chngcntr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf}, skip=5pt]{caption}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{setspace,geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs, makecell, caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[round, sort&compress]{natbib} %sort&compress orders in text citation automatically
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx} %setze S in Tabelle, um nach dem Punkt auszurichten
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[bottom,hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} %footnotes always appear on bottom and not end of text on single page
\geometry{a4paper, top=30mm, left=30mm, right=30mm, bottom=30mm,headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}

%try to prevent widows and orphans (single lines on top/bottom of page)
\widowpenalty10000 
\clubpenalty10000

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=30mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=30mm,headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.7\hsize}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{heatmap_bull_unscaled.png}\hspace{.25cm}
\caption{Sub figure A}
    \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
%\hfill <-- it is superfluous 
\begin{subfigure}{0.7\hsize}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{heatmap_bear_unscaled.png}
\caption{Sub figure B}
    \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure in landscape orientation}
    \label{fig:sub2}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\restoregeometry


\end{document}
```

I want them to be next to each other, like here, but without the spacing between them:

[image]

Comment: How you like positioned these pictures? One above other or that they are parallel?

Comment: I cant reproduce your result. In case, that images are parallel, there is no vertical space between them, in case that images is one above other, the space is very small. Unfortunately I cant test this with your images.  It can be, that they are to large that can be fit in one page.

Comment: Off-topic: Do you really need all package which you load in document preamble? Many of them are loaded twice ... Please, clean-up your preamble and then provide MWE which has only relevant package needed to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant reproduce your result with test images provided by `graphicx` package with option `demo`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=30mm, left=30mm, right=30mm, bottom=30mm,headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}
\usepackage[demo, export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=30mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=30mm,headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{heatmap_bull_unscaled.png}
\caption{Sub figure A}
    \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{heatmap_bear_unscaled.png}
\caption{Sub figure B}
    \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure in landscape orientation}
    \label{fig:sub2}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you cant reproduce similar result with your actual images means, that images has white space around them. This you can check with enclose `\incledegraphics...` into `\fbox`:

```
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}
\fbox{
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{heatmap_bull_unscaled.png}
    }
\caption{Sub figure A}
    \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}
```

I f white space is there, you can trim it out for example with tools in program by which they are generated, or with some other tools or with appropriate settings of `trim` options in `\includegraphics`:

```
\includegraphics[trim={5cm 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}
```

where **trim** modify the bounding box specified in the file. The four values specify the amounts to remove from the left, bottom, right and top of the original box; and **clip** clip the graphics to the bounding box (specified with trim)

Comment: Thanks, the \fbox hint helped :)